I have a little 8-in chainsaw I need a new blade it has 45 Drive links can I put a 48 Drive link chain on my 45 with everything else being the same
I have an 8-in chainsaw and it has 45 Drive links I can find a 48 Drive links chainsaw with everything else matching the manufacturers specifications can I use the different Drive links

If everything else for the specs are the same, then three drive links can be removed.  Number of drive links is the length measurement of the chain.  Could buy the tools needed, but a local chain shop should do it for a few bucks and make sure it is the right chain.

you can take out 3 links, you need a hammer and pin driver, to knock the out
